# Grep multiple positions with/without ID

Tags: bash, awk, grep, pattern-matching, vcf-variant-call-format

I want to grep a vcf file for search for multiple positions. The following works:

```
grep -f template_gb37 file.vcf>gb37_result
```

My template_gb37 has 10000 lines and it looks like this:

```
1   1156131 rs2887286   C   T
1   1211292 rs6685064   T   C
1   2283896 rs2840528   A   G
```

When the vcf has the rs it works perfect.

The problem is that the vcf I am going to grep may not have the rs and "." instead:

File.vcf

```
#CHROM  POS  ID  REF  ALT ....
1   1156131 .   C   T  ....
1   1211292 .   T   C  ....
1   1211292 .   T   C  ....
```

Is there a way to search my multiple patterns with "rs" or just "."?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I removed the [tag:vcf] tag; per the tag description, it's used for vCard files.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean the second field in your file could be `.` or `rsNNNNNN` and you want to allow either. So, I think you need an *"alternation"* which you do with a `|` like this:

```
printf "cat\nmonkey\ndog" | grep -E "cat|dog"
cat
dog
```

So your pattern file `"template_gb37"` needs to look like this:

```
1   1156131 (\.)|rs2887286   C   T
1   1211292 (\.)|rs6685064   T   C
1   2283896 (\.)|rs2840528   A   G
```

And you need to search with:

```
grep -Ef PATTERNFILE file.vcf
```

---

If you don't want to change your pattern file, you can edit it *"on-the-fly"* each time you use it. So, if `"template"` currently looks like this:

```
1   1156131 rs2887286   C   T
1   1211292 rs6685064   T   C
1   2283896 rs2840528   A   G
```

the following `awk` will edit it:

```
awk '{$3 = "(\\.)|" $3}1' template
```

to make it this:

```
1 1156131 (\.)|rs2887286 C T
1 1211292 (\.)|rs6685064 T C
1 2283896 (\.)|rs2840528 A G
```

which means you could use my whole answer like this:

```
grep -Ef <( awk '{$3 = "(\\.)|" $3}1' template ) file.vcf
```

Comment: You seem to have put parenthese in the wrong places. I guess that should be `(\.|rs2887286)` etc.

Comment: ... But the existing answer IMHO solves this more elegantly with a single Awk script.

Comment: @triplee If the OP is happy to edit his pattern file, I feel it is better than the `awk` solution, because it becomes `grep -Ef PATTERNFILE file.vcf`. And anyway, I didn't say it was better, it's just another possibility to consider :-)

Comment: Thanks @tripleee and Mark for your both answers. I do not mind changing the template file so this approach matches perfect what I need. I also think the "only" grep approximation is a more beautiful solution.

Answer (score 2):

Seems better to use `awk` for this, your data format is what it wants, columns. First parse the (fixed) patterns, save them, also create the extra ones with dot instead of the `rs...`. Then matches lines from second file.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1 $2 $3 $4 $5]; a[$1 $2 "." $4 $5]; next}
     ($1 $2 $3 $4 $5) in a' template_gb37 file.vcf > gb37_result
```

Comment: Thanks @thanasisp for your answer. Your approximation is interesting but I think the grep approximation is a better option.